# Not able to draw vertical lines between textview

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have been looking for this and not getting it. Here is a snapshot of the image I want.

I have added the `marginTop` attribute to design the vertical lines and hence am not able to get the full line. Please help. Thanks in advance!
[image]
I am also posting my xml file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_val"
            android:background="@drawable/display_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/displayImgView"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/third_icon_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/thirdIconImgView"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
            android:background="@drawable/tools_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/toolsImgView"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/your_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/homeLstView"
                android:divider="@null"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemCountTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/placed_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_vertical_line"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                android:text="@string/subtotal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtotal_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtotal_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_horizontal_line"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="$4 Shipping:"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipping_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipping_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="$7.75 Tax:"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tax_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tax_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_horizontal_line"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="@dimen/total_text_size"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/total_val_text_size"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/sevenTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/eightTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/nineTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/clear_all"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/clrAllTxtView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/fourTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/fiveTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/sixTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/clear_last"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/clrLastTxtView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/oneTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/twoTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/threeTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_cross_selected"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/arrowCrossImgView"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/calculator_horizontal_divider_val"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/zeroTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/point_zero"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/pointZerosTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/plus"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/addTxtView"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/discount"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/discountTxtView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i cant see an image attachment?

Comment: no image attachment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a layout_height of those `ImageViews'` static value `30dp` and some unnecessary `View`. Hope this will solve your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/displayImgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_val"
            android:background="@drawable/display_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thirdIconImgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/third_icon_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolsImgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
            android:background="@drawable/tools_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/your_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/homeLstView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@null" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemCountTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/placed_items"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_vertical_line" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/title_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                android:text="@string/subtotal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtotal_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtotal_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_horizontal_line" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="$4 Shipping:"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipping_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shipping_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="$7.75 Tax:"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tax_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tax_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/placed_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/line_margin_val"
                android:background="@drawable/dotted_top_horizontal_line" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="@dimen/total_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_b4_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="$0."
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/total_val_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_after_dec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/left_margin_val"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sevenTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eightTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nineTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/clrAllTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/clear_all"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fourTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fiveTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sixTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/clrLastTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/clear_last"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oneTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twoTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/threeTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrowCrossImgView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_cross_selected"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calc_horizontal_divider"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zeroTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pointZerosTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/point_zero"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/plus"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/calc_vrtical_divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discountTxtView"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/discount"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shipping_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```